# python packaging with code depending on a shell script

Tags: python-packaging

If a python package depends on executing a shell script, where in the package should that script go?  Assuming the following structure

```
cobra
|__ pyproject.toml
|__ src
    |__ cobra
        |__ __init__.py
        |__ bite.py (a function here needs to call the shell script)
|__ tests
    |__ defence.py
|__ doc
    |__ rtfm.pdf
```

I don't need to make the script easily available to end users.

Comment: It is "*package data*", so it should be anywhere inside the top-level import package. In your case it means inside `src/cobra`.

Comment: So I treat it as any other resource and call it by obtaining its full path with importlib.resources. It makes sense thanks.

Comment: Yes, very important to use `importlib.resources`, do not rely on the value of `__path__` or `__file__` or anything like that (because there is no guarantee about directory layout once installed, you should not assume the file will be here or there).